# Quicker command for fraktur letters than \mathfrak?

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting, typesetting

There is a shorthand way of writing letters in blackboard bold: instead of using \mathbb, we use \Bbb. This substantially sped up my time writing questions and answers on math.SE. In the course of composing a question about rings, I started to wonder:

> *Is there a shorcut way of typesetting Fraktur letters (e.g. $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{p}$) that is to \mathfrak what \Bbb is to \mathbb?*

I haven't seen one used on the site, but if it exists, it would again speed up my time writing questions & answers. Anyone got an idea?

(*Note:* I understand that one can define personalized commands at the start of answers, but I'm talking about something that I can use without defining a shortcut, like \Bbb.)

Comment: `\frak` is similar to `\sf` or `\rm` or `\bf`, and all of those are different from `\Bbb`.

Comment: @AsafKaragila When I use \frak it seems to make everything else in the dollar signs fraktur, even when I only want to apply it to a specific letter.

Comment: Add brackets `${\frak A}BC$` to get ${\frak A}BC$.

Comment: Since there is `\mathfrak`, why is there no `\textfrak` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\frak` is similar to `\sf` or `\rm` or `\bf` (they all change the font), and all of those are different from `\Bbb` (which only affects the next group).

$${\frak F\in A}\quad\text{ vs. }\quad{\Bbb F\in A}$$

Comment: Is there a \frak-like command that will only affect the text I put in curly braces?

Comment: No. Just like there isn't one for boldface, sans serif, or even Roman. Blackboard bold is the outlier.

Comment:  Less versatile than I had hoped for, but still useful. Appreciate finding out about the other three font commands as well. Thank you!

Comment: You can still scope it with {\frak ...}

Comment: Fancy seeing you here, @Peter, thanks for the comment. I should have mentioned that, yes. (In fact, I did in the answer itself... :-))